# Symfony2 Nested CollectionType form w/ Dependency injection data not saving

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, nested-forms

I have a problem with the dependency injection, and saving it to the database, I have a following `formType` inside another form which i use in two different controller routes which handle the same entity: Creating a new entity and editing it. When i'm trying to create a new entity and set `$user` field for it, it will save user field as empty string.

```
    class SomeClass extends AbstractType
    {
        private $tokenStorage;
        private $user;
        public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
        {
            $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
        }
        /**
         * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
         * @param array $options
         */
         public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)   {
             $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
             $builder
                ->add('price', null, array(
                    'label' => 'price',
                    'required' => true,
                    'translation_domain' => 'some_translation',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'placeholder' => 'price'
                )
            ))
                ->add('user', HiddenType::class, array(
                    'data' => $user
            ));
            // dump($user);
            // exit(0);
         }
```

I have tried it out and dumped it and debugged and what i've found out is that when i dump $user i get the proper data i need `firstName`, `lastName` etc. , but when i submit the data it does not save it to the database instead i get empty string. Then i dumped out the whole form after submit in the controller and found out that the user field is null. 
However it does work when i go to edit route and edit the existing entity, but if i create new entity on the edit form it does work on the one that exists, but not the newly made entity.

I have also checked the controller and the Entity class itself and those are not the problem.

Comment: Why don't you just get the 'user' in the controller and set it on the object before persisting it? Is there any reason why you are passing the user value in a hidden input? Are you using that value on the form view?

Comment: Because the form is set in a manner that i can create new entities on the fly, so getting the correct user out of the form might be quite hard task. I have now found out also what the problem is in symfony's prototypes. I dont know yet how to fix this, but i now know where the problem is and what is causing it.